# Is there an infinite number of proofs for the Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: geometry

It seems there are many, many proofs for the Pythagorean Theorem, but is there an actual upper limit? It seems every type of math has several different proofs for it, and there seems to always be new ways. I've seen books with over 300+ proofs. Is it possible there may not an upper limit?

Comment: If a variation of an argument by $\epsilon \in \Bbb Q$ is counted as a new proof , we have countably infinitely many proofs. So the question first is, how do you define for two proofs to be not only similar but equivalent.

Comment: Take any proof.  Stick some irrelevant steps in the middle.  Voilà, another proof.

Comment: There aren't an infinite number of *anything*.  Now get off my lawn!

Comment: Why did you delete your cool question on ring theory, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903903/units-in-quotient-ring-of-nilpotent-ideal-are-units-in-the-original-ring ??? I was just about to answer it!  Maybe you could undelete it? ***Cheers!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:**

In a right triangle of side lengths $a$ and $b$,
$$a^2+b^2=(c-3)^2$$

where $c$ is the length of the hypothenuses, plus $3$.

**Proof:**

Number 42 from the 300+ book, adapted.

**Theorem:**

In a right triangle of side lengths $a$ and $b$,
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

where $c$ is the length of the hypothenuses.

**Proof:**

By the lemma, $a^2+b^2=(c+3-3)^2$.

---

I can generate as many such proofs as you want by replacing $3$ by any other number.

Comment: Not kidding, this is what happens with those proofs.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess my question was a bit silly then, cause if those two proofs count as different almost anything can be proved infinite ways... Thanks

Comment: @Lollie: the fact is that it is challenging to tell if two proofs are different, in a semantic way.